# The universal cover and embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Whether there exists a  non-simply connected complete Riemannian manifold $(M^n, g)$ such that  it can be $C^2$-isometric (globally) embedded into some Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^p$, but its Riemannian universal cover  can not be $C^2$-isometric embedded into $\mathbb{E}^p$? (What would happen if we let the target be other open simply connected complete Riemannian manifolds?)